# How to use JAXB to process messages from two separate schemas (with same rootelement name)

Tags: jaxb

We have a client that is sending xml messages that are produced from two separate schemas.

We would like to process them in a single application, since the content is related.

We cannot modify the client's schema that they are using to produce the XML messages...

We can modify our own copies of the two schema (or binding.jxb) -- if it helps -- in order to enable our JAXB processing of messages created from the two separate schemas.

Unfortunately, both schemas have the same root element name (see below).

QUESTION:  Does JAXB prohibit absolutely the processing two schemas that have the same root element name?
-- If so, I will stop my "easter egg" hunt for a solution to this...
---Or, is there some workaround that would enable us to use JAXB for processing these XML messages produced from two different schemas?

schema1 (note the root element name: "A"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="A">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="AA">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="AAA1" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="AAA2" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="AAA3" type="xsd:string" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BB">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="BBB1" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="BBB2" type="xsd:string" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

schema2 (note, again, using the same root element name: "A")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="A">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="CCC">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="DDD1" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="DDD2" type="xsd:string" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="EEE">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="EEE1">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="FFF1" type="xsd:string" />
                                        <xsd:element name="FFF2" type="xsd:string" />
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name="EEE2" type="xsd:string" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

> QUESTION: Does JAXB prohibit
>   absolutely the processing two schemas
>   that have the same root element name?

ANSWER: You can have multiple classes mapped with the same root element, but you need to specify the type on an unmarshal operation.

**A1**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="A")
public class A1 {    
}
```

**A2**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="A")
public class A2 {    
}
```

**input.xml**

```
<A/>
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A1.class, A2.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xmlFile = new File("input.xml");
        StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
        A1 a1 = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlSource, A1.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(a1, System.out);
    }
}
```

**For More Information:**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/handling-duplicate-xmlrootelement.html

---

The following is an example bindings file that can be used to customize the class that an element is mapped to.  I don't see any relationship between the two schemas.  Are you somehow combining them is a single XJC operation?

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema1.xsd">
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='A']">
                <jxb:class name="RenamedA"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Hi Blaise We are using JAXB to generate the classes used and the generator complains/fails due to the identical root elements. Is there a workaround that will enable the classes to be generated using, for instance, the binding.jxb configuration file?

Comment: Yes,  I had been trying to combine them as they are needed in a single application.... --Since, I have been attempting to combine the two schemas (using groups) as you suggested... --I used the "Answer your own question" post, because I needed the space,  to illustrate what I am trying to do...Please see my "answer"... Still not working, but, it may be that I am incorrectly using binding statements... Thankyou for looking at this.  Been very informative.

Answer (score 1):

I tried combining the two schemas (that use the same element name) as you suggested earlier.

***(note: I had to use the "Answer your own question" posting in order to include the examples, since the comment allows only limited space)***

One problem I am having is that some of the sub-elements in the actual schema (I cant post the actual schema) use the same names (I had to recreate, below, to illustrate this case... -notice that schema1 and schema2 "group"s contain elements having the same name)...

Here is the schemacombo.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:group name="schema1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AA">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="CC1" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="CC2" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="BB">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="DD1" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>   
    </xs:group>
    <xs:group name="schema2">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AA">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="CC1" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="CC2" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="BB">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="DD1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="EE1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="EE2" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:element name="A">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:group ref="schema1" />
                <xs:group ref="schema2" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>    
</xs:schema>
```

I've tried running

```
xjc schemacombo.xsd -b binding.xjb
```

...where binding.xjb contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               jaxb:version="2.0">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation = "schemacombo.xsd" node="/xs:schema">>
      <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="xs:group[@name='schema2']">
            <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jxb:modelGroupName suffix="2"/>
            </jxb:nameXmlTransform>         
        </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

...-A weak attempt, I know, and it does not work...i.e., running this yields:

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_A'. Multiple elements with name 'AA', with different types, appear in the model group.
  line 49 of file:/C:/AAAAA_delegate/schemacombo.xsd

[ERROR] cos-nonambig: AA and AA (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.
  line 49 of file:/C:/AAAAA_delegate/schemacombo.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Do you have any suggestion for bindings statements or annotations that would fix this.   --Note, I have still not seen customized binds work, yet.

Comment: I did not see your "answer your own question" when I commented on my other answer.  you have the same issue here that you originally did when I suggested using the choice/group reference.  you have definitions for the same element with differing types.  you cannot do that and expect the schema to be valid. (this isn't perl code after all ;-) )  I don't think you'll be able to nicely modify your schema in a way to get around all these duplicate element definitions. in this example you could move the AA into a sequence definition in the "A" element complex type. (continued in next comment)

Comment: but the definition of the DD1 element as both a simple type (string) and a complex type is really what prevents you from overcoming your issue in this case.  I can't think of a way around this other than to follow my other suggestion from the other answer, which is to generate your JAXB stubs separately for each schema, and attempt to parse your message using both JAXB contexts with validation enabled..  it's not clean by any means, but it might allow you to deal with this situation better than trying to munge the schemas into some semblance of unity. square peg, round hole know what I mean?

Comment: Undertand.   And, thanks for your efforts, Helter!..   --At the very least you've helped me to stop wasting my time on a dead end path.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the problem isn't that the root elements both have the same name, it's that they are defined as exactly the same element -- meaning same name and same namespace. you wont be able to deal with these schema's quite the way you want.

what you can do, although it does mean lots of maintenance work for you is to combine the definitions of both schemas into a single definition utilizing a choice and group references, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:group name="schema1a">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="AA">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="AAA1" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="AAA2" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="AAA3" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="BB">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="BBB1" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="BBB2" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:group>

<xsd:group name="schema2a">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="CCC">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="DDD1" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="DDD2" type="xsd:string" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="EEE">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="EEE1">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="FFF1" type="xsd:string" />
                                        <xsd:element name="FFF2" type="xsd:string" />
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="EEE2" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:group>
    <xsd:element name="A">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:group ref="schema1a" />
            <xsd:group ref="schema2a" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

essentially we take the complex type definitions of each schema's A element and change them to a group definition, then we include those group definitions into a choice element.  this would effectively allow the jaxb parser to deal correctly with documents that are produced with either schema.  it is a lot of workto maintain this between updates of either schema.. but perhaps this can be automated using XSLT and some scripting.

hope this helps

Comment: Hi Blaise

That was my topic on StackOverflow you cited.

Your answer is informative but doesn't address my poorly-worded question.

What I'm trying to do is generate classes using the two schema for a single application.

So far, I have been unsuccessful.  

The JAXB generator complains that the element "A" (i.e., the root element) is already defined.

I've tried my hand at using a bindings file, but, because I've never seen this work, I don't know if I'm incorrectly coding the bindings file or if my version of JAXB is incorrect, etc.

Can you make this work?

Thanks!

jw

Comment: The actual schemas also have sub-elements with the same name, as well.   After combining the two schemas as you suggested (thanks for that tip), I now get `[ERROR] cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_A'. Multiple elements with name 'AA', with different types, appear in the model group.
  line 69 of file:/C:/AAAAA_delegate/schemacombo.xsd`... This is because both schemas that I have combined contain the "AA" element name. Is there a method of overcoming this "collision"?   What I've tried thus far -- i.e., in the way of custom bindings/annotations -- has not worked.

Comment: it would be helpful to see your actual schemas. without this it is very hard to suggest a solution that will work.  my suggestion was based on the sample you provided which had non-unique "A" elements but with unique sub-element structures. it may be possible to fix your latest problem us a jaxb customization file, but I won't know until I have more information.

Comment: a different solution you may consider is using jaxb to compile the different schema's separately into different packages, and then attempt to parse the message (with validation turned on) using two different jaxb contexts. the one that parses without a validation error is valid. this has it's problems as well from ugly code to maintenance to what do you do if the schema's aren't sufficiently unique enough to differentiate a given message...

Comment: Hi Helter - you can see below in the discussion trail, below, that I combined the two schemas into a single schema -- i.e., called "schemacombo.xsd".  -Each "group" element in "schemacombo.xsd" contains the contents of the original schema1.xsd and schema2.xsd, respectively.  Except that the root element "A" -- which used to be the same for both the original schemas -- now contains a "choice" element with references to "schema1" and "schema2" group elems.  -- Problem is how to resolve the collision errors:  `...Multiple elements with name 'AA', with different types, appear in the model group.`